# Pandas groupby().get_group().size does not return correct size?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm grouping a DataFrame of every countries' demographic data. I find problem with I want to get the size of each group, .size or np.size() returns the sum of first column of the group, instead of count of rows.

I'm using Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.23.4

```
df.groupby('foo').apply(lambda grp: grp.size)
```

this returns the a much larger number.

```
Countries.groupby('foo').apply(lambda grp: grp['some colum'].size)
```

this will give correct count

Anyone knows why the `.size` works different in each case? Thanks!

Comment: It's actually my first post in the community. Please let me know if I the question or writing is not clear. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Try `Countries.groupby(ContinentDict).size()`

Comment: What is `ContinentDict` in this? Provide a [mcve] please?

Comment: I edited the question to look cleaner. Scott's code works. But why when I use  `.size` inside `.apply` will have wrong output?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas GroupBy.get_group constructs a DataFrame. You called [DataFrame.size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) which returns the count of elements in the object. To get the number of rows in the group, try

```
Countries.groupby(ContinentDict).get_group('Asia').shape[0]
```

Comment: Thanks Vaishali, this works and I'm trying to understand